# Interpretar dados vindos de um arquivo externo para usar no Autocomplete

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Tenho o seguinte arquivo:

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function montaAutocomplete(source) {


 $( function() {



    var availableTags = [ source ];

    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });

  } );

}

</script><script>
function busca_palavra(x){

  $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "autocomplete_sugestoes_descricao.php?q=" + x,
    dataType:'text',
    success : function(data) {

        montaAutocomplete( data );

      }
    });

}
</script>
```

E o arquivo que gera o resultado:

**autocomplete_sugestoes_descricao.php**

```
<?php

require "../conexao_ajax.php";


$q                 = preg_replace("/[^0-9A-Za-z]-/", "",$_GET['q']);

$q_formatado       =  '%'.$q.'%';


if(!empty($q)){ 
    $busca_descricao = $link->prepare("SELECT id, descricao FROM ctrl_bancario WHERE descricao LIKE ? ORDER BY descricao ASC LIMIT 10");

    $busca_descricao->bind_param("s", $q_formatado);

    $busca_descricao->bind_result($id, $descricao);

    $busca_descricao->execute();

    $busca_descricao->store_result();

    if($busca_descricao->num_rows() > 0){

        echo "[";


        while ($busca_descricao->fetch()) {

            echo "$descricao, "; 

        }// Esta chave fecha o while ($busca_descricao->fetch()) { 

            echo "]";

       } // Esta chave fecha o if($busca_descricao->num_rows() > 0){


} // Esta chave fecha if(!empty($q)){   

?>
```

Estou conseguindo receber os dados normalmente, entretanto, se tenho dois registros em minha tabela:

[image: registros]

a minha aplicação está retornando os dados desta forma no **autocomplete** do **index.php**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como se não houvesse uma quebra de linha ou uma correta interpretação dos dados.

Como eu poderia proceder no momento de tratar esses dados vindos do arquivo `autocomplete_sugestoes_descricao.php` na variável  `var availableTags = [ source ];`?

Espero obter este resultado:

[image: resultado_final]

Comment: Seu problema parece estar no "availableTags ", tem como postar ela junto da pergunta?

Comment: O resultado da minha consulta retorna exatamente assim: [Depósito de Teste , teste, ]

Comment: E o "availableTags" está sendo declarado no primeiro script do arquivo index.php

Comment: Estou me baseando neste exemplo para construir o meu: https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/default.html

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema esta no formado dos dados:

```
[Depósito de Teste , teste, ]
```

Deve conter aspas ou apóstrofe.

```
var teste = ["Depósito de Teste" , "teste", ];
```

Use `json_encode` para seu php retornar* no formato correto

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

```js
  $( function() {
   
      var dados= ["Depósito de Teste" , "teste" ];

     $( "#teste" ).autocomplete({
      source: dados
    });
  } );
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="teste">teste </label>
  <input id="teste">
</div>
```

Comment: Quando uso as 'sugestões' de forma estática, ele exibe sem problemas, entretanto, quando requisito com o autocomplete_sugestoes_descricao.php ele ainda retorna nessa única linha

Answer (score 1):

Compile todos os dados vindos do banco dentro de um array e depois devolva o array para o seu ajax usando [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php).

```
if ($busca_descricao->num_rows() > 0){
   $result = array();

    while ($busca_descricao->fetch()) {
        $result[] = $descricao;
    }
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Isso vai retornar um array formatado em

```
success: function(data) {
}
```

Comment: Usei o seu trecho de código. Ele apenas me retornou um: [true,true]

Comment: @netoweb Erro meu. Editei.

Comment: Ele me retornou ["Dep\u00f3sito de Teste\r\n","teste"] quando testado no arquivo autocomplete_sugestoes_descricao.php e tbm na aplicação principal, ainda assim exibindo tudo na mesma linha. Eu teria que tratar esses dados em success: function(data) {
} ? - Se sim, como procederia ?

Comment: Isso provavelmente está relacionado à forma como o dado foi gravado no banco de dado, seja pela forma como foi enviado, seja pela forma como foi guardado (formatação do campo na tabela). Precisa investigar, mas já é outra questão.

Comment: Bruno. Dê uma olhada nesta minha resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/233780/76180
e me diga se é seguro usar desta maneira.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui achar uma solução:

```html
var dados = [ source ];

var availableTags = JSON.parse(dados);
```

Ela funcionou perfeitamente, me retornando este resultado:

Seria seguro usar desta maneira?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa é a solução para um problema extra, não responde a questão inicial que é como retornar os dados formatados.

Comment: Não há nenhum problema em utilizar o JSON.parse nesse cotexto, até onde sei.

Comment: Funciona, mas penso que deve padronizar sua API, fazendo-a retornar apenas JSON, usando `echo json_encode($result);` nos retornos do seu php. caso contrario você precisa ficar fazendo parse* no seu JS.